# java variables not being initialized

Tags: java, initialization, bluej

I have the following code which outputs 0 and 5 when run the first time.  However, if I rerun the program I get 5 and 5 from BlueJ (ide) and 0 and 5 from coding roooms (ide).  Is this a bug in BlueJ?

UPDATE: spoke to the BlueJ support team.  BlueJ has an extension called "Run Main Method" that is causing the problem.  If you use void main(String[] args) the program runs as intended

here's the code:

```
public class Bug
{
    private static int x = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("\f");
        
        System.out.println(x);
        x=5;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a bug since it seems the `Bug` class is not reloaded after the initial run. But maybe it's just an issue with a run configuration.

Comment: Have fun searching whether a bug report already exists, otherwise file one: http://bugs.bluej.org/projects/BLUEJ/issues/BLUEJ-1366?filter=allopenissues ... where it is VERY surprising that such a problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is probably a bug in BlueJ as both in Eclipse and IntelliJ the output is

```
0
5
```

In any case the above should be the correct output in any IDE as per the rules of the Java language